# How do i make a message box appear if DBNULL occurs

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a problem where if i search for data via a `TextBox` and the data *doesn't exist* in the database i get the error

> 'Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.'

I am trying to make a `MessageBox` appear to say *data doesn't exist* and cannot figure out how to do this.

I have tryed using an `if` statement where if the `TextBox` equals `DBNull` then a `MessageBox` appears.  this doesn`t work and im not too sure why. The error occurs with me trying to **equal** to`DBNull`. How do i produce a`TextBox` saying data doesnt exist?

```
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("***COnString**");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM (Total_Hours_Day) FROM Sign_In_Out_Table, User_Table WHERE User_Table.FirstName = '" + Search_Username_Alerts_Admin_txtbox.Text + "' AND Sign_In_Out_Table.eb_number = User_Table.eb_number AND Date between GETDATE()-14 and GETDATE()", con);
        decimal TotalHoursFortnight = Convert.ToDecimal(comm.ExecuteScalar());
        con.Close();

        decimal sum = 0;

        sum += Convert.ToDecimal(TotalHoursFortnight);

        if (Search_Username_Alerts_Admin_txtbox.Text == DBNull)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Data Exists");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Search_Username_Alerts_Admin_txtbox.Text + ":" + Environment.NewLine + " Hours Worked = " + TotalHoursFortnight, ("Working Info Admin"), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
}
```

My *expected result* is for a *message box* to appear saying data doesn't exist if searched for.  but if it does the data will show in a message box.

Comment: BTW you just created SQL Injection. Imagine what happened when I type into `Search_Username_Alerts_Admin_txtbox.Text` following string `a'; DROP TABLE Sign_In_Out_Table; --`

Comment: To prevent the SQL injection do i need a line of code under the SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand line with a parameters.Add(new sql parameter(Total_Hours_Day)  etc?  or is this done a different way.  @PiotrStapp Srapp

Comment: @Johnathan there is an answer that shows you how to use parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use decimal.tryparse to see if data was returned

```
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("***COnString**");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM (Total_Hours_Day) FROM Sign_In_Out_Table, User_Table WHERE User_Table.FirstName = '" + Search_Username_Alerts_Admin_txtbox.Text + "' AND Sign_In_Out_Table.eb_number = User_Table.eb_number AND Date between GETDATE()-14 and GETDATE()", con);
            string TotalHoursFortnight = (comm.ExecuteScalar()).ToString();
            con.Close();

            decimal sum = 0;
            decimal temp;
            if(!decimal.TryParse(TotalHoursFortnight, out temp)) 
            { 

                MessageBox.Show("No Data Exists");
            }
            else
            {
                sum += temp;

                MessageBox.Show(Search_Username_Alerts_Admin_txtbox.Text + ":" + Environment.NewLine + " Hours Worked = " + TotalHoursFortnight, ("Working Info Admin"), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
```

Comment: Beware!  If there are no records returned by the query this code will crash with a nullreference exception at the ToString() after the ExecuteScalar. Also this answer doesn't solve the Sql Injection problem so it should really not considered as the best answer here

Answer (score 2):

You have **3** cases to implement:

1. *No* data at all: check for `null`
2. *Invalid* data, e.g. `1 + 2 + NULL + 3 == NULL`: check for `DBNull.Value`
3. *Valid* data, e.g. `1 + 2 + 3 == 6`: convert it with a help of `Convert.ToDecimal()`

**Code:**

```
// wrap IDisposable into using
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("***COnString**")) {
  con.Open();

  //DONE: Make sql readable
  //DONE: Make sql parametrized
  //TODO: you may want to change eb_number = eb_number into INNER JOIN
  string sql = 
    @"SELECT SUM (Total_Hours_Day) 
        FROM Sign_In_Out_Table, 
             User_Table 
       WHERE User_Table.FirstName = @prm_FirstName  
         AND Sign_In_Out_Table.eb_number = User_Table.eb_number 
         AND Date BETWEEN GETDATE() - 14 AND GETDATE()"; 

  using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
    //TODO: Better specify RDBMS type explictly with "comm.Parameters.Add(...)"
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(
      "@prm_FirstName", Search_Username_Alerts_Admin_txtbox.Text); 

    var result = comm.ExecuteScalar();

    if (null == result) {              // No Data
      MessageBox.Show("No Data Exist");
    }
    else if (DBNull.Value == result) { // We have the Data and it's RDBMS Null
      MessageBox.Show("Data Exist, but not valid.");
    } 
    else {                             // We have a valid Decimal
      Decimal sum = Convert.ToDecimal(result); 
      //TODO: put the relevant code here
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need check null for query result

```
var result = comm.ExecuteScalar();
    if(result != null){
         decimal TotalHoursFortnight = Convert.ToDecimal(comm.ExecuteScalar());
         // move remain code to if block
    }
```

And `if (Search_Username_Alerts_Admin_txtbox.Text == DBNull)` should change to

```
if (Convert.IsDBNull(Search_Username_Alerts_Admin_txtbox.Text){

}
```

Comment: It returns `DBNull.Value`, not `null`, if the result is `NULL`. Needs to test for that instead.

Comment: ExecuteScalar returns null not DBNull.Value, however re-executing ExecuteScalar should be avoided.

Comment: @Steve - That is incorrect. I just called `ExecuteScalar` on `SELECT NULL` and it returned `DBNull.Value`. But you are right about executing twice.

Comment: Dapper will return `null`, but OP is not using Dapper.

Comment: @madreflection Of course your example returns DBNull.Value, but you are assuming a wrong conclusion from that example. ExecuteScalar returns null if there is no row produced by the query text. It returns DBNull.Value if there is a row and the first column contains null. Your example returns a row and its first column contains null.